# Why am I getting Swift error "Use of extraneous '&'"?

Tags: swift

I'm building a class, and, when defining one of the functions, I get the error "Use of extraneous '&'". I don't know what it means, and I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using Xcode 10.1. I'm trying to update a dictionary (named numOrders) contained in a Struct (named bidBook) by using the notation bidBook.numOrders[order.price] += 1 (where order.price is a variable contained in another Struct).

Lines 71, 72 and 87, 88 in main.swift produce the error.

The code can be found at https://github.com/cgit2017/Thesis in Thesis/main.swift.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy and paste the relevant code (as text) into your question pointing out which lines are causing errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why that error happens, but for me it disappears when I change the lines to

```
bidBook.numOrders[order.price]! += 1
bidBook.priceSize[order.price]! += order.quantity
```

EDIT: Previously I assumed that it was due to `bidBook.numOrders[order.price]` returning an optional. This is not the issue since it works fine in other lines. Nevertheless the approach above works for me.